# ColdFusion - No matching function [functionName] found

Tags: cfml, lucee

This code works on my dev environment but not in the production environment. I am loading the CFC into the session scope, in case that matters. You can see from this dump that the CFC does have a function called `getQuestions` but the function that calls to it isn’t finding it. I get the error

> "No matching function [getQuestions] found".

`getQuestions` is a function that was added since my last push.

I have checked the server configs for both the dev and the prod server and they are the same so I am not sure why this is happening. Prod environment is a VM if that makes a difference. Can anyone shed any light on this one?

[image]

Comment: Did the signature of the function change? Are you loading to the session scope or application scope? If the latter, did you reload the application?

Comment: I am loading it into the session scope.  If I load it right before the test it works but then when I remove the load from the test it doesn't work almost like there are two different session scope locations. If that makes sense.

Comment: Add code to your Application.cfc to ensure that your Session is completely timed out. It sounds like you're still running through your old session.

Comment: Looks like you need to call the function `this.getQuestions()`

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate an object (an instance of a CFC), it stays as that object, with that version of the class it came from (the .cfc file), until it is de-scoped and eligible for garbage collection.

A very short version of what you did may look like this:

```
// Write a component
fileWrite("a.cfc", "component { function foo(){return 'bar';} }");

// instantiate that component
a = new a();
writeOutput(a.foo()); // writes "bar" to the page

// now let's rewrite the file
fileWrite("a.cfc", "component { function bar(){return 'foo';} }");

writeOutput(a.foo()); // still writes "bar" to the page
writeOutput(a.bar()); // error - no such method
```

Changing the definition of `a.cfc` does not mean the variable `a` changed - it's still the old version.

Now, you put your Survey object in the session scope. That scope is persisted until the session ends - it has to time out due to inactivity or the server needs to reboot. You can delete it from the session using `structDelete()` or overwrite it (`session.survey = new Survey()`), but until one of these things happens, your session will still carry the old survey object.

For scenarios like this, I tend to make a session reset, so I can add `?sessionreset=true` and put some code in Application.cfc's `OnRequestStart()` to look for that and clear out my session. You'll also want to do this for application-scoped variables.